# Delegates variance

Tags: c#, delegates, variance

I'm having a hard time to understand why `Action<T>` is contravariant and `Func<T>` covariant , why should `Action<T>` be contravariant and why should `Func<T>` be covariant, any guidelines about when to use one and when to use the other .

Comment: Action<T> is for void functions. Func<T> is for returning functions

Comment: Do you understand what covariance and contravariance mean to start with? It's not clear which piece of the puzzle you're missing at the moment.

Comment: I understand the use of the two , but I don't understand why Contravariance in Action<T> , why contravariance reverses the subtyping in T . why ?

Comment: *"any guidelines about when to use one and when to use the other"* - forget about words containing "variant" (unless you have a case where it's matter, then post it), only keep in mind this: use `Func<>` if you return value and `Action<>` if you don't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `Action<T>` were covariant you would be able to do this:

```
Action<string> sa = s => { Console.WriteLine(s[0]); }
Action<object> oa = sa;
oa(1);
```

and pass an `int` to an action with a string parameter, which is not safe. It is safe to go the other way and narrow the parameter type e.g.

```
Action<object> oa = o => { Console.WriteLine(o.GetHashCode()); }
Action<string> sa = oa;
sa("test");
```

since any `string` is also an `object`.

Comment: so it's all about type safety ? no other reasons ?

Comment: @ZakaryaIsser - variance was added to delegate and interface parameters to allow safe assignments to be expressed in the type system. In C#3 and earlier you would not be able to make these assignments, so variance increased the flexibility of the type system without sacrificing safety. I doubt C# will add type system features which are unsound.

Comment: Thank you very much sir this is a very clear consise explanation , you ansered the why :)

Comment: should it be s[0] instead of sa[0]

Answer (score 1):

An `Action<T>` takes a `T` as an input and returns nothing, so it can be contravariant.

A `Func<T>` takes no input and returns a `T`, so it can be covariant.

They serve different purposes and are not interchangeable.

In general, an interface can be *covariant* when it only uses the generic parameters in *outputs* (e.g. methods that return a `T` but do not take `T` as an input, read-only properties).

The classic example is `IEnumerable<T>`.  it only *returns* `T`s - it does not have any methods or properties that take a `T` an an *input*.

An interface can be *contravariant* when it only uses the generic parameter(s) only as *inputs*

One example of this is [`IComparer<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ehhxeaf.aspx).  It takes two `T`s and determines if they are equal to (or if one is "greater than" the other").  It has no return values that are based on `T`.

> when should I make my custom delegates Covariant and when make them contravariant ?

A delegate can be covariant if it only *returns* `T`s.  It can be contravariant if in only has *inputs* that are `T`s.

Comment: thank you for the quick reply , so when should I make my custom delegates Covariant and when make them contravariant ?

Answer (score 1):

Here's some annotated code that might also help you understand in detail.

It uses an Animal / Cat / Dog class heirarchy to illustrate why contravariance and covariance is the way it is for `Action<T>` and `Func<T>`.

```
using System;

namespace Demo
{
    class Animal
    {
        public virtual void MakeNoise() {}
    }

    class Dog: Animal
    {
        public override void MakeNoise()
        {
            Bark();
        }

        public void Bark() {}
    }

    class Cat : Animal
    {
        public override void MakeNoise()
        {
            Meow();
        }

        public void Meow() {}
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void handleAnimal(Animal animal) // I can handle cats AND dogs.
        {
            animal.MakeNoise();
        }

        static void handleCat(Cat cat) // I only handle cats.
        {
            cat.Meow();
        }

        static Cat createCat() // I only create cats.
        {
            return new Cat();
        }

        static Dog createDog() // I only create dogs.
        {
            return new Dog();
        }

        static Animal createAnimal() // I only create animals.
        {
            return new Animal();
        }

        public static void Main()
        {
            // Action<T> is contravariant.

            // Since the parameter of handleAnimal() is of type Animal,
            // it can handle both cats and dogs. Therefore Action<Cat> 
            // and Action<Dog> can both be assigned from it.

            Action<Cat> catAction = handleAnimal;
            Action<Dog> dogAction = handleAnimal;

            catAction(new Cat()); // Cat passed to handleAnimal() - OK.
            dogAction(new Dog()); // Dog passed to handleAnimal() - OK.

            // Imagine that Action<T> was covariant.
            // Then you would be able to do this:

            Action<Animal> animalAction = handleCat; // This line won't compile, because:
            animalAction(new Animal());              // Animal passed to handleCat() - NOT OK!

            // Func<T> has a covariant return type.

            // Since the type returned from Func<Animal> is of type Animal, 
            // any type derived from Animal will do.
            // Therefore it can be assigned from either createCat() or createDog().

            Func<Animal> catFunc    = createCat;
            Func<Animal> dogFunc    = createDog;
            Func<Animal> animalFunc = createAnimal;

            Animal animal1 = catFunc();    // Cat returned and assigned to Animal - OK.
            Animal animal2 = dogFunc();    // Dog returned and assigned to Animal - OK.
            Animal animal3 = animalFunc(); // Animal returned and assigned to Animal - OK.

            // Imagine that Func<T> was contravariant.
            // Then you would be able to do this:

            Func<Cat> catMaker = createAnimal; // This line won't compile because:
            Cat cat = catMaker();              // Animal would be assigned to Cat - NOT OK!
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow perfect , this is a great sample with the comments

Answer (score 0):

The difference between Func and Action is simply whether you want the delegate to return a value (use Func) or not (use Action).
Func is probably most commonly used in LINQ - for example in projections:

`list.Select(x => x.SomeProperty)`

or filtering:

`list.Where(x => x.SomeValue == someOtherValue)`

or key selection:

`list.Join(otherList, x => x.FirstKey, y => y.SecondKey, ...)`

Action is more commonly used for things like `List<T>.ForEach`: execute the given action for each item in the list. I use this less often than Func, although I do sometimes use the parameterless version for things like Control.BeginInvoke and Dispatcher.BeginInvoke.

Predicate is just a special cased Func really, introduced before all of the Func and most of the Action delegates came along. I suspect that if we'd already had Func and Action in their various guises, Predicate wouldn't have been introduced... although it does impart a certain meaning to the use of the delegate, whereas Func and Action are used for widely disparate purposes.

Predicate is mostly used in `List<T>` for methods like *FindAll* and *RemoveAll*